# Regex for n-directory file path

Tags: regex, scala

I'm trying to use regex to evaluate if a given path is valid or not:

List of acceptable values:

```
 1. /a_B_1/b_Sc2/c_d3/23_DS_xy/some_file_name.txt
 2. /x_y_q/ffs/www/A/a_ol/some_file_name.txt
 3. /tsf/ggg/wWw/abc/a_o@l/some=file name.csv
 4. /a/b/c/d/some file.txt
```

As you can see for all groups, accepted range is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Only the last group can have `spaces, @, =`.

Group ordering: `/<group1>/<group2>/<group3>/<group4>/<group5>`.

Group 5 can have sub-directories and hence the `'*'`.

I've tried:

```
"""/?[^/\\n]+/([^/\\n]+)/([^/\\n]+)/([^/\\n]+)/([^/\\n]+)/.*""".r

"""/(^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/(^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/(^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/(^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/(^[a-zA-Z0-9-_\\s]*)""".r

"""/([\\w,\\s-_]+)/([\\w,\\s-_]+)/([\\w,\\s-_]+)/([\\w,\\s-_]+)/([\\w,\\s]*)""".r
```

Can someone please guide?

**Sample code**

```
val regex = """ ... """.r
val testString = "/a/b/c/d/some file.txt"
regex.findFirstMatchIn(testString) match {
    case Some(r) => println(r)
    case _ => println("Regex did not match")
}
```

Comment: Don't use regex for this. Split it on directory separators and evaluate them on their own

Comment: the first example doesn't seem to be acceptable by the rules you've described: the _fourth_ "group" in that example contains a `=`...

Comment: @TzachZohar: you're right. I've updated my code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your question is, but note that you don't need to escape backslahes inside triple-quoted strings.

Something like this `"""(/\w+){4}/([\w\s@=/]+)""".r` seems like it should do what you are describing.

Comment: This does not work for sub-directories. For instance, it fails to capture the file name in : `/a/b/c/d/e/some file.txt`

Comment: Sorry, fixed that.

Comment: Thanks! your approach is much elegant

Comment: The last group `([\w\s@=/]+)` would leave out `.txt` in the testString.  I think `(.*)` would suit better, assuming no additional trailing text.  Another minor note, while `(/\w+){4}` gives a lean look, it makes group extraction a little tricky, as `group(1)` would now be the 4th group and `group(2)` would be the 5th.